# Is there any concurrent issue with gorm create function?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm with mysql in my Go app.

Here I apply gorm create() function to insert my struct which contains auto-increment id as primary key.

```
type DBModel struct {
    ID  int64  `gorm:"column:id;primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    ...
}
```

Actually after create, a "select" would be called to fill this struct with last insert data from db.

So what if several create happens together? Say I create model_A, model_B ... at same time, would all of them get correct data?

As I check from gorm, `create()` is the combination of `insert` and `select from last_insert_id`. How would gorm/mysql ensure correct last_insert_id after insert?

Comment: that is the responsibility of the implementation of the mysql db engine. You have to study the source of the engine to figure out how this happens precisely. https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server